# using media queries to resize a page when a window is minimized

Tags: html, css

I would like to know,is there a way that i can use only one media query that will keep my contents in the exact position when i shrink an html page? Im not sure if this is possible as i havent been able to find anything. I can set the max-width and min-width that when my page shrinks to a certain size it must use the elements that i assigned it. I just feel its kind off untidy for me to keep on setting the width of a page.So i was wondering is there a way where i can do everything in one query.

this is how i use my media tags currently

```
    @media (max-width: 1024px) and (min-width: 768px) {
    #Logo {
        top: 5px;
        width: 250px;
    }

    #TabBar {
        margin-right: -14em;
    }

    #btnLogout {
        margin-left: -39px;
    }

    #displayBalance {
        margin-right: -95px;
    }
   }
    @media(max-width:1029) {
    #TabBar {
    margin-right:-18em; // like for example here i have to keep on assigning a different width to the same div
    }
}
@media (max-width: 1097px) and (min-width:647px) {

    #btnLogout {
        margin-left: -39px;
    }
}


@media (min-width: 1024px){
    .footer_nav .logo {
        margin-left:20%;
    }
}
```

or should i do something like this in jquery?

```
$('#body').css('min-height', '100%');
```

Comment: you can try specifying the values with %

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep everything the full width of the page just use `width:100%;`. Otherwise media queries can be really powerful in keeping everything exactly how you want it, so maybe use % values to start with, and only include media queries when necessary?

If I understand your issue correctly if you assign a % value to margin-left on #btnLogout this should change responsively. Without seeing your code/page it's difficult to advise.